# How to create a fetch primary key of the updated table on which we create a trigger?

Tags: sql, triggers, database-trigger

I have a Product table and a ProductPriceLog table to maintain price of a product.
Assume product table has 3 fields `[ProductId, ProductName, ProductPrice]` and price history just has 2 fields `[ProductId(fk), productprice]`

I am attempting to write a trigger which would add a log entry each time we update the price of the product.

```
CREATE TRIGGER price_change_trg
ON PRODUCT
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF ProductPrice ON PRODUCT
BEGIN

     INSERT INTO ProductPriceLog ( @idd , ProductPrice)
END;
```

Specifically, how to I fetch the productId from the Product table's row which was updated?

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer my solution. Hope to help, my friend.

```
CREATE TRIGGER price_change_trg
ON PRODUCT
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
declare @productId int;
declare @ProductPrice decimal(10,2);
select @productId = i.ProductId from inserted i;
select @ProductPrice = i.ProductPrice from inserted i;  
     INSERT INTO ProductPriceLog VALUES ( @productId  , @ProductPrice )
END;
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if statement affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @productId = i.ProductId from inserted i;` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Why i try this in Microsoft SQL server management studio, why do i get a red underline under table name ProductPriceLog in the following ```INSERT INTO ProductPriceLog ( @productId  , @ProductPrice )``` ProductPriceLog has been created before so I am not sure, why this error.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper: Sorry, my friend. I missed Values keyword front of ProductPriceLog table.

Answer (score -1):

If i understood your question you must use **inserted** table that has data that just inserted in product table`select @idd=productid from inserted`